# What is the access code for the Night Terror's cell?

Tags: wasteland-2

In the Darwin Village lab, what is the access code for the Night Terror's cell (in the room with the three gun turrets along the "back route" to the air filtration system)?

Comment: I am pretty sure they are randomized

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is ICEBERG. Please let me know if you have troubles.

It can be found by examining one of the tables.